# Trying to install package for MikTex from CTAN but cannot find tpm file (dirtytalk)

Tags: packages, miktex

I recently transferred a LaTex script I wrote in Overleaf to my PC to start working with MikTex instead.

In the process of trying to compile the file for the first time, there were several packages I needed to install that I was using in Overleaf.

In this case, the package is called [dirtytalk](https://ctan.org/pkg/dirtytalk?lang=en). When I download the package contents from the website, I do not see a .tpm file. There is a .ins file, but I'm unsure what to do with it.

[image: Folder]

I want to continue to use all the packages from the original file I made in Overleaf, **but the more pressing issue for me is how do I find the .tpm file if it's not in the package contents on the website?** This can become a recurring issue, and I was wondering if there is any fix or suggestion.

When I try to look it up using the MiKTeX console, it does not appear.
[image: Console]

Comment: You would not expect tpm files from ctan (I have never see one but I assume it's a miktex package?) you should obtain the file using miktex package manager not from ctan.

Comment: Thanks. I tried looking for it in the MiKTeX console but it did not appear.

Comment: or as you have the files now just run latex on `dirtytalk.ins` and it will generate `dirtytalk.sty` which you can save in your document folder, but installing via miktex would be better

Comment: I'm new to MiKTex, how do I "run latex on `dirtytalk.ins`"? Can you write an answer with screenshots? Sorry in advance if that's a "dumb" question.

Comment: I have never used miktex but just do what you would do for any tex file. I would open  command window and cd to the folder and type `tex dirtytalk.ins` but you can probably load the file into your tex editor and use some menu to run latex

Comment: OK, so just run the dirtytalk tex file?

Comment: it has extension `.ins` but it is a tex file

Comment: I was able to run the .ins file and create the .sty file. But I am unsure what to do with it now.

Comment: so now you should have a dirtytalk.sty so save that in same place as your document

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: The ctan page says that the package is only in texlive and not in MiKTeX,  so you can't currently install it with the package manager. But you could make a feature request at the MiKTeX github and ask to include it.